# Как избавиться от приставки #!/ в адресной строке шаблона

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся на этот шаблон [link text](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_40655/index.html#!/home)

и ни как не могу избавиться от "приставки" (#!/), которая автоматом добавляется в адресной строке после index.html . Я как бы нашел в каком файле происходитработа скрипта по "приклеиванию" (#!/) это файл switcher.js . Все мои попытки что то проделать с кодом в этом файле по изменению или удалению (#!/) приводят к неполному отбражению контента страницы сайта! Подскажите, как избавиться от этой приставки (#!/) в адресной строке сайта или же если не избавиться, то хотя бы заменить #!/ на /site/ ????

Comment: @Павел Страный, если Вам необходимо выполнить работу за деньги, воспользуйтесь [Карьерой](http://careers.hashcode.ru/).

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то # - это якорь, очень часто используется на сайтах с динамической загрузкой страниц, т.к. его изменение не требует рефреша страницы. Вот и в Вашем случае js-движок использует document.location.hash для навигации на сайте. !/page_more или !/home - это так сказать адрес открытой страницы. При заходе на страницу js читает этот хэш и определяет какой контент показать. Всё что можно привести к более эстетичному виду, это убрать !/

Comment: Не могу комментировать ответ @Deonis. Хочу сказать о минусах таких сайтов:
1. Отсутствие возможности SEO-оптимизации сайта. Поисковики игнорируют данные после #.
2. Именно на этом шаблоне будет проблематично в целом избавиться от динамической загрузки страниц, она, я бы сказал, "псевдодинамичекская". Весь контент находится на одной странице в скрытых div'ах, а c помощью javascript меняется видимость этих div'ов

Comment: @t0di, есть же 2 типа:

 1. контент всего сайта загружается сразу
 2. по изменению # через XJR подгружается с других страниц

Вы сейчас видимо говорили о №1. 1. Присутствует. Но поисковики не игнорируют данные, находящиеся на странице. Так или иначе эти данные попадут в выдачу. К тому же хорошим тоном к таким сайтам есть прикрутка статических страниц того же вида (есть js - меняем видимость | нет js - переходим по сссылке на статику), где контент тот же самый. Является обычной ситуацией в №2

Comment: `#!` "придуман" гуглем как раз для индексации аяксовых сайтов. 
 
* Статья про Гугль. [тыц](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=ru)
* Статья про Яндекс. [тыц](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=1125296)

Comment: Ух, не знал) Век живи - век учись)

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно согласен с [[@t0di](/users/9347/t0di)](/users/9347/t0di). В [этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114911/), вы даже  сможете уловить суть этих манипуляций. Могу только добавить, что "*избавиться от этой приставки (#!/)*" можно несколькими путями:

1. Убрать hash-навигацию, переписав часть скрипта, отвечающего за вывод информации из БД. Потратите уйму времени, прежде, чем получите нормальный результат.
2. Убрать вывод хэша в адресную строку. В этом случае, у вас строка изменяться вообще не будет, но перестанет работать "история", т.е кнопки "назад"(на предыдущую страницу)/"вперед"(на следующую страницу). Исправляется достаточно легко: найти строку/строки, где будет примерный код и закоментить её:

   ```
   location.hash = someVar // someVar - или переменная, или какое-то стринговое значение
   // !!!Не перепутать с
   var someVar = location.hash // так получаете хэш
   ```
3. Вариант третий - это использовать [HTML5 History API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/). Решение достойное, но т.к. вы, насколько я понимаю, далеки от программирования, то времени вы потратите на решение этой задачи - значительно больше, чем в варианте первом.

P.S. Думаю, что вам надо расслабиться )) И получать удовольствие от того, что сайт у вас работает без перезагрузок, а к этому сейчас многие стремяться.

Comment: @Deonis, согласен, кроме того, что многие стремятся:) Стремяться те, кто делают домашние странички, проект более-менее крупный откажется от такой затеи

Comment: @stck - twitter, gmail, vk, как я понимаю, не достаточно крупные? :(

Comment: @AlexWindHope, подменяете понятие на масшатбность. Или я подменяю. Для меня крупный === Сложный, Большой, Многофункциональный !== Малофункциональный, Известный

Comment: ОМГ, вы хотите сказать что перечисленные мною проекты простые и малофункциональные? Вы из паралельной вселенной?

Ну вот серьезно, реально бесит когда люди пишут о том, в чем ничего не понимают

Comment: @AlexWindHope, да именно это и хочу сказать. Нет, из Вашей же. Допустим твиттер можно расписать ~40-45 шаблонных страниц, в то время, как существуют проекты >1500 шаблонных страниц (e.g. технические платформы). Если Вас бесят люди, которые пишут о том чего не понимают, правильно ли Вы делаете, что являетесь участником вопросника такого? Здесь люди постоянно пишут о том, чего не знают, или Вы мазохист?)

Comment: @stck я имел введу утверждения людей, о том, в чем не разбираются, вопросы, догадки и т.д - это нормально

Как-бы количество "шаблонных страниц" никак не говорит о том, что проект сложный и уж точно никак не говорит о том, что в нем неудобно( нельзя, неуместно ) отказаться от перезагрузки страниц, ну да не важно, все-равно все останутся при своем мнении.